# VB .NET backgroundworker rare behaviour

Tags: vb.net, listview, delegates, backgroundworker

The problem is very strange. I have a form (`Form1.vb`) with a button (`Button1`), a ListView (`ListView_orders`) and a BackgroundWorker (`BackgroundWorker1`). I have a Module file called (`Functions.vb`) with a some Sub in it. These Sub a made for BackgroundWorker1 to call when needed.

The problem is how to add items to ListView_orders by BackgroundWorker1 when it is calling a Sub in the Functions module. I know it is hard to understand me now. Another way to tell the problem is "A Sub in the Functions.vb module is made to add items to ListView_orders. When the BackgroundWorker1 is calling this Sub, it wont add any items to ListView_orders".

**PS**

- **I set all Modifiers to Public**
- **I have added a delegate method to invoke from BackgroundWorker1-thread**
- **I've spent more than 7 days to find a solution to my problem.**

Here is my code:

## Form1.vb

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    ListView_orders.Items.Add(ListView_orders.Items.Count + 1).SubItems.AddRange({"directrun", "b", "c"})
End Sub

Public Delegate Sub terminalAddInvoker(ctrl As Object)
Public Sub terminalAdd(ctrl As Object)
    If ctrl.InvokeRequired Then
        ctrl.Invoke(New terminalAddInvoker(AddressOf terminalAdd), ctrl)
    Else
        Dim item As New ListViewItem(CStr(ctrl.Items.Count + 1))
        item.SubItems.AddRange({"a", "b", "c"})
        ctrl.Items.Add(item)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Adder(ctrl As Object)
    terminalAdd(ctrl)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    addthings()
    terminalAdd(ListView_orders) 'works (backgroundworker, calls the invoke delegate method)
    Adder(ListView_orders) 'works (backgroundworker, call a sub which calls the invoke delegate method)
End Sub
End Class
```

## Functions.vb

```
Module Functions
Public Sub addthings() 'sub called from backgroundworker
    Form1.ListView_orders.Items.Add("Hello") 'doesnt work (directly)
    Form1.terminalAdd(Form1.ListView_orders) 'doesnt work (calls the invoke delegate method of Form1)
    terminalAdd(Form1.ListView_orders) 'doesnt work (calls the invoke delegate method in the same file)
    Form1.Adder(Form1.ListView_orders) 'doesnt work (calls a sub in Form1 which calls the invoke delegate method in Form1)
End Sub

Public Delegate Sub terminalAddInvoker(ctrl As Object)
Public Sub terminalAdd(ctrl As Object)
    If ctrl.InvokeRequired Then
        ctrl.Invoke(New terminalAddInvoker(AddressOf terminalAdd), ctrl)
    Else
        Dim item As New ListViewItem(CStr(ctrl.Items.Count + 1))
        item.SubItems.AddRange({"a", "b", "c"})
        ctrl.Items.Add(item)
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

## More info about the code

In `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork()`, there are 3 lines of code. Two of them adds an item to ListView_orders, but the `addthings()`Sub wont add any item. In `addthings()` Sub there are 4 lines of code trying to add items to ListView_orders, but non of them works. **It should be adding items.** . The thread is still the same. Just because it is in a different file, it doesn't work.

**Please help.**

Comment: Standard vb.net problem, the vile default instance "feature" at work.  Using "Form1" in your module is the problem.  When you call those methods from a worker thread then Form1 is *not* the instance of the Form1 that you are looking at.  It is a new one, it is not visible because its Show() method was never called.  You'll have to throw this code away, it is unfit to do the job.  Use a BGW properly, its ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events run on the UI thread.  The only places where you can safely interact with UI objects.

Comment: hello, thank you for answering. I erased Form1 in my module and passed the Form1 from the BackgroundWorker_DoWork to the Sub as a parameter, and it worked. I know I am not using a BGW properly, but I dont find a better to do what i wanted. Anyway, I've found a solution because of you. If you write an "answer", i will accept it.